# I cannot INSERT INTO Variable to MYSQL with Python3

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, sql-insert

```
import MySQLdb
# Open database connection
payload_list = ["10","20","30","40"]
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","","","iot" )

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

# execute SQL query using execute() method.
sql = "INSERT INTO iot_data (data_ip,data_mac,data_humidity,data_temp,data_time) VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '$s', NOW()))"
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO iot_data (data_ip,data_mac,data_humidity,data_temp,data_time) VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '$s', NOW()))",(payload_list))

# Fetch a single row using fetchone() method.
db.commit()

# disconnect from server
db.close()
```

**Error**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "db.py", line 13, in
>   
>       cursor.execute("INSERT INTO iot_data (data_ip,data_mac,data_humidity,data_temp,data_time) VALUES('%s',
>   '%s', '%s', '$s',
>   NOW()))",(payload_list[0],payload_list[1],payload_list[2],payload_list[3],))
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 210, in
>   execute
>       query = query % args TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: try removing quotes around `%s`

Comment: Thank you, very useful answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import datetime
import MySQLdb
# Open database connection
payload_list = ["HI",2,3,4]
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","","","iot" )

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()
your_date = "2017-01-12 19:51:44"
# execute SQL query using execute() method.

sql = """INSERT INTO iot_data (data_ip,data_mac,data_humidity,data_temp,data_time) VALUES(%s, '%s', '%s', '%s', NOW())"""
cursor.execute(sql,payload_list)

# Fetch a single row using fetchone() method.
db.commit()

# disconnect from server
db.close()
```